# Can unverified contracts expose a public ABI?

Tags: etherscan, abi

I am trying to understand if there are unverified contracts that come with a public ABI. 
I was exploring contracts on Etherscan, and I was only able to find unverified contracts without source code and without ABI. Are all unverified contracts like this? Or is it possible to find unverified contracts with a public ABI?
Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean "public API"? If they're not verified on Etherscan, then their ABIs are not public on Etherscan.

Comment: Thank you for your help! Well I know that unverified contracts have private source code, but I was trying to understand if the ABI is always private as well. So I was wondering if you can have a contract with private source code and a public ABI.

Comment: There's no such thing as privacy of the source code (and subsequently its interface, i.e., the ABI). With a bit of effort, you can unveil the source code of any contract, whether it is verified on Etherscan or not. The verification is just for transparency (i.e., for user to trust in your contract being genuine), since obviously, any legal contract between two parties should be fully disclosed to those parties.